# Accessing div tag inside ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

```
I want to access "chart_div"

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="list-style-2" "user in results.users">
    <li ng-repeat="atmpt in user.attempts" >
     {{$index+1+':'}}
        Marks: <span class="label label-info">{{atmpt.marks+' / '+atmpt.total_marks}}
        </span> 
         | Percentage: <span class="label label-success">{{atmpt.percent+'%'}}</span> 

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="chart_div" class="graph"></div>

    </div>
</script>
```

for my google graph api as

```
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
```

I'm getting an error as "container not found".

Any help appreciated
Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

Never do DOM manipulation outside of directives.  If you are in a controller or a factory or somewhere else and you're accessing DOM elements stop and use a directive.  The directive is applied to the elements it effects and keeping the controllers and other code free of DOM access means they can be tested without regard to a particular view.  Modifying DOM elements from random places in the code makes it very difficult to pin down why a particular element ended up in a particular place or with whatever attributes/styles are set on it.

There are existing modules that have directives for manipulating/creating Google Charts, if one doesn't do what you want you can write your own (not really that hard once you've written one directive you can write them all basically :) )

A basic Google Chart directive is shown below

http://plnkr.co/edit/aY5SBetA1KJ12YpphVt0?p=preview

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('googleChart', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
      function drawChart(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(element[0]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to have it in a directive. Can you help me passing parameters to drawChart() from controller??

Comment: This is a good question. I too have a directive that contains bootstrap ng-template directives. I need to know if there is a way to access the html inside the template for the sake of testing (jasmine)

Comment: @MarkGlass what version of angular are you using? this was in the context of angular 1.x so probably not that relevant anymore tbh, now you can use annotations to create references I believe with templateRef or other mechanisms but the versions is going to matter